# Dropdown issue on iPad Safari

Tags: html, css, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I have a dropdown list coded as follows;

```
<select name="xyz" class="selectbox" size="6"/>
```

Now as it says size=6 , that means it should display 6 options at a time. While this works fine in desktop browsers like IE, FF, the same does not work correctly on the iPad Safari..

i.e. it shows it like a normal dropdown with 1 option visible at a time.

Is there any fix to correct this issue on iPad?

Comment: According to this forum page, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2637434?threadID=2637434, Safari on iOS does not support the `size` option.

Comment: Thx for your reply...Well the same forum also says "Safari does, indeed, support the size attribute (with the lower limit of 4)."

Also it did try the same on desktop Safari and it works fine ...But only on iPad Safari, it does not work..

Comment: that's the point. The normal computer based Safari and Chrome support it. Not iOS based (iPod, iPad, iPhone) Safari, as far as I know. I tried a few websites yesterday on my iPhone and an iPad and they all did the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the 'multiple' attribute to true. It will still not look the way you want it to look, but at least you will be able to select multiple items from the list.